Is it possible to disable the automatic UPC checksum check in TCPDF?
I'm using TCPDF to generate a page of retail store bin tags. These tags include a 1D UPC barcode. The system has worked for years, save for one problem: manufacturers and/or distributors occasionally send out a UPC with the wrong checksum.
By the time the data gets to me, it's set in stone. My customer is a $1M/year retailer dealing with multiple $10B/year distributors. They'll never be able to wag that dog and they've been politely told the problem won't be fixed. Undoubtedly that number has become deeply embedded into who knows how many databases and reports.
And it causes TCPDF to error out when trying to generate a barcode. Yes, I can go find the correct checksum number, but that changes the 12-digit barcode, which is all that matters. I need to generate a scannable barcode regardless the final number.

I am using type UPCA (UPC_A).
The error I'm getting is TCPDF ERROR: Error in 1D barcode string
My sample UPC is: 417489022098 (the check digit should be 4, but c'est la vie).

Is there a way to disable the checksum check in TCPDF?
If not, is there a barcode type that's a UPC-style barcode that doesn't use a checksum check? I'm unfamiliar with most of the barcode types supported by TCPDF and the documentation doesn't even mention this check.

You didn't say which exact barcode you're using, so I am assuming UPC-A. You also didn't say what the exact error message is. If UPC-A would be the one you're using, you could start by removing the check at line 160 in this file. It causes errors like: "Invalid check digit: 3". Of course you need to make sure that this library then doesn't auto-update at some stage, because that would again remove your edits.

@KIKOSoftware Thank you for pointing out the missing conditions. I've added them. I'm not receiving the error you're suggesting. However, thanks again for pointing out the github location. I'll start perusing the files. You're right that I'd prefer not to modify a file, but if that's my option, not updating won't bite me as quickly as not dealing with this.

The line to comment out is this one.

@Olivier While it took a bit to get back to printing those tags (the retailer is resetting a large portion of their store) I wanted to thank you for pointing out the correct line to remove. It worked like a charm. I can print the tags and the scanners work just fine with them. Do you want to turn that into an answer and let me slap some rep on you?

When printing an EAN/UPC barcode, TCPDF checks the checksum digit and throws an error if it is incorrect. There is no setting to disable that behavior, so you need to change the code. The most simple way is to comment out a line in the TCPDFBarcode::barcode_eanupc() method:
} elseif ($r !== intval($code[$data_len])) {
            // wrong checkdigit
//          return false;
        }

